# Custom Unwind Segue Crashes with NSException in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

I have an unwind segue that I would like to have a custom animation.

I have a custom segue class:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class SegueFromRight: UIStoryboardSegue {

override func perform() {
    let src: UIViewController = self.source
    let dst: UIViewController = self.destination
    let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
    let timeFunc : CAMediaTimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.duration = 0.25
    transition.timingFunction = timeFunc
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
    src.navigationController!.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    src.navigationController!.pushViewController(dst, animated: false)
    }
}
```

I have defined the unwind segue:

```
@IBAction func unwindToGameOver(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
}
```

I call the segue on button press:

```
@IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToGameOver", sender: self)
}
```

Here's my interface builder for the unwind segue:

[image: interface builder]

It crashes with "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

The custom segue works on a show segue & the unwind segue works when I remove its class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an unwind segue and your custom segue is pushing. But an unwind segue in a navigation controller would be a pop, not a push.

Frankly, nowadays you'd use [custom transitions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/218/), rather than subclassing a segue, but if you change it to pop, it works.